# IOUtils copy method is not working properly

Tags: java, methods, io, copy

The copy method gives me this error:

"*The method copy(InputStream, OutputStream) in the type IOUtils is not applicable for the arguments (FileInputStream, StringWriter, String)*"

... even though I have 3 parameters and that IOUtils does have the

`copy(InputStream, Writer, String)` method.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AboutDialog extends JFrame {
    private final String fileLocation = "resources/Contents.html";
    private FileInputStream htmlStream;
    private JLabel lblMessage;

    public AboutDialog() {
        String message;
        setType(Type.POPUP);
        setTitle("About");
        setResizable(false);
        setEnabled(false);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        try {
            htmlStream = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(htmlStream, writer, "UTF-8");
            message = writer.toString();
            lblMessage = new JLabel(message);
            lblMessage.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            getContentPane().add(lblMessage);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    public void display() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, lblMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your import may be wrong, you probably wanted to use _org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils_ and not _org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils_ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean to import `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils` instead of `org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils`.

The former has a lot of `copy()` methods the latter only has `copy(InputStream, OutputStream)`.

Answer (score 1):

IOUtils from apache POI contains only the 2 params method. https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/util/IOUtils.html